# Animate inner views in MotionLayout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-motionlayout

I was able to animate views that are within `MotionLayout` but couldn't animate views that are inside another view that is inside `MotionLayout`.

```xml
<androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout
...
    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
     ...
       <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout

<!-- I need to animate views that are here when the RecyclerView is scrolling -->
        ...
       </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
     </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

<TextView/>
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>
```

Is there a way to animate the views that are inside the `MaterialCardView` when scrolling the `RecyclerView`?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

MotionLayout can only animate its children.

There are two ways that you might do this..

1. Flatten the layout to something like this:

```xml
<androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout
   ...
   <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
   </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView> 
   <!-- I need to animate views that are here -->
        ...
   <TextView/>
   <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>
```

The card view will below the widgets and you can constrain to the CardView as you would the ConstraintLayout (where you used parent)
This would also be more performant.

2. You can not use MotionLayout track the scroll and implement your own transition.
3. You can use code to listen to the progress of of the MotionLayout and drive the views directly

Comment: I tried your first solution before asking here, but it didn't work as expected, because I need to put views inside the `CardView`, trying to mimic the content like it is inside the `CardView` using constraints didn't seem to look good, as well as the collapsing animation didn't work.

Comment: Having a layout try to modify another layouts content will generate conflict as to "who  is  right". So If you can't make flat work you would need to do something custom. (code)